# Use python in html using evaluation tag

Tags: html

I want to use for loop in html. I have a python array, I want to use it in html and this is in demisto platform - "ConvertTabletoHTML automation". I dont want to use javascript or pyscript , instead want to use <% %> - evaluation tags.

I tried this way :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <% for i in range(10): %>
    <%= i %>*<%= i %> : <b> <%= i*i %> </b>
    <% end %>
    <h3>done</h3>
    </body></html>
```

It is displaying :

```
<% for i in range(10): %>
    <%= i %>*<%= i %> : <b> <%= i*i %> </b>
    <% end %>
```

How can I write using evaluation tag?

Comment: What the heck is an “*evaluation tag*”? I’m not aware of any such thing in the HTML specification, can you link the documentation upon which you’re basing your implicit claim to the contrary?

Comment: “*I want to use for loop in html.*” HTML on its own is purely a ***markup*** language - it has no semblance of control structures or logical functions like this.

Answer (score 1):

I *assume* you're trying to get [Cortex XSOAR](https://xsoar.pan.dev/)'s [`ConvertTableToHTML`](https://xsoar.pan.dev/docs/reference/scripts/convert-table-to-html) output to generate in a way akin to something like the [HTML Encoding syntax from ASP.NET](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2). This cannot be done, as HTML is a *markup* language, which means that it is impossible to create control structures.

While XSOAR may run ASP.NET under the hood, you cannot control *their* server-side logic (as doing so would be a security concern). Instead, what you should be doing is processing the logic on *your* end, then sending the desired structure back to XSOAR. Examples of how to do this can be found on their [Python conventions page](https://xsoar.pan.dev/docs/integrations/code-conventions).

Comment: Thanks for your response. yes, I am using XSOAR. Sorry, I am using this in send-mail task , "htmlbody". This is to send email using htmlBody option there.

Javascript is not working. Can I use pyscript ?